# LPVOID issue wont accept memory address

Tags: c++

I did look around for a while on forums as well as MSDN and cant seem to find what my issue is here. I am sure this is simple for non noobs like me. I am trying to compile a simple program and it does not like my code.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int score = 80000;
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "3D Pinball for Windows - Space Cadet");

if (hwnd == NULL)
{
    cout << "Cant find window";
    Sleep(3000);
}
else {
    DWORD ProcID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &ProcID);
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcID);
    cout << "Found it:  "; cout << ProcID;
    WriteProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)00F7D9CC, &score, sizeof(score), 0);
    Sleep(5000);
}

    return 0;
}
```

Much of this is just from me messing around, hence the messy code that doesnt make sense.  I am trying to change the score on the pinball game and I got the memory address from cheat engine and I can change the address value on there and watch it change while the game is played. It only actually changed the score in the game one time, and never again which I cant figure out either.  But my main objective was to try to change the score with my own program instead of cheat engine. I wanted to use cheat engine mainly to find the address only. Anyway the address is the section of character after the LPVOID. E2474,C3688,C2660 are the errors that come up. Any help would be appreciated to get me unstuck.

Comment: The token `00F7D9CC` is the octal number `0` followed by the letters `F` and `D`. It's not a valid symbol in C++.

Comment: Additionally, [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) and windows security things may very much get in the way here. I would not expect it to be easy to mess with the memory of other processes.

Comment: That is something I had never come across during my searches.  Thank you,  I learned something from both of you  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

`WriteProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)0x00F7D9CC, &score, sizeof(score), 0);`

Numbers starting with 0 are octal numbers. Base8 can only contain digits 0...7, so this token is not valid at all.

Comment: One simple x added in, and no more errors. Thanks so much!

Comment: since it has the letters, this would be considered base 16 hexadecimal correct? I just thought it was weird that when I found this memory address it was displayed plainly, without the 0x at the beginning. Thanks again for the response.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
(LPVOID)00F7D9CC
```

To

```
static_cast<LPVOID>(0x00F7D9CC)
```

And it should resolve your compile issue.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'll be trying that soon as I get a chance, which will be tonight.  I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @dkpaintball8488 don't forget to mark the answer as correct.